# openssl, unexpected eof while reading:ssl\record\rec_layter_s3.c:309

Tags: openssl, domino-appdev-pack

I make use the following scripts to create a self-signed certificate,
however, when I try to verify the SSL certificate, with the following error message.

The certificate is created by the following command:
C:\Certs>set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
openssl genrsa -passout "pass:rootPassword" -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -passin "pass:rootPassword" -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/O=Org/CN=OrgCA" -sha256

```
    C:\Certs>openssl s_client -connect serv.org.com:3002 --quiet -CAfile C:\Certs\ca.crt
    depth=1 O = Proton, CN = Proton Certificate Authority
    verify error:num=19:self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    verify return:1
    depth=1 O = Proton, CN = Proton Certificate Authority
    verify return:1
    depth=0 O = Proton, CN = 192.168.176.130
    verify return:1
    50090000:error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:309:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, as the Proton server is not a normal web server. There is no continuation of normal HTTP traffic.